# How do I apply patch in vendor directory using composer?

Tags: 8, composer, testing

Background:

- Drupal 8
- Managing dependencies with compose

I want to apply one patch to `vendor/behat/web_api_extension` project.

I tried with this in `composer.json` but it doesn't works or no error.

```
"extra": {
    "enable-patching": true,
    "patches": {
        "drupal/better_formats": {
           "Settings have no affect on the field if it is in a Paragraph bundle - https://www.drupal.org/node/2754029": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/better_formats_paragraphs-2754029-15.patch"
        },
        "vendor/behat/web-api-extension": {
            "behat web api definition conflicts with mink extensions": "patches/behat_web_api/alter-definitions-text.patch"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to have a patching workflow, you need something like Composer Patches. https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches - the format should be `vendor/project`, so, `behat/web-api-extension`. I have not tried this outside of Drupal module patches though.

Comment: @Kevin my drupal module patches works fine. i tried with `vendor/web-api-extension` but it don't work. My vendor directory is outside drupal root does it effect?

Comment: `vendor/project` is the EXAMPLE format - you should use `behat/web-api-extension`, not `vendor/`

Comment: @Kevin i did same but no hope :(

Answer (score 6):

You will need `cweagans` vendor to make composer able to parse the extra->patches lines.

This line is wrong I think: `"vendor/behat/web-api-extension"`
You always need the package name (without version) and not the relative path.
In your case it should be `"behat/behat"`

Answer (score -1):

You need to have `cweagans/composer-patches` as a requirement on your project, so you need to:

```
composer require cweagans/composer-patches
```

Then in your composer.json you need to add your patches under extra:patches, which you already had:

```
...
"extra": {
    "enable-patching": true,
    "patches": {
        "drupal/better_formats": {
           "Settings have no affect on the field if it is in a Paragraph bundle - https://www.drupal.org/node/2754029": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/better_formats_paragraphs-2754029-15.patch"
        },
        "vendor/behat/web-api-extension": {
            "behat web api definition conflicts with mink extensions": "patches/behat_web_api/alter-definitions-text.patch"
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: This answer only rephrase the OP question.